# Derivative of real-valued function must be real-valued

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is an exercise from Bak/Newman and I'm stuck:

Suppose $f(z)$ is real-valued and differentiable for all real $z$. Show that $f'(z)$ is also real-valued for real $z$.

My first idea was to assume that $f'(z)$ was complex and then show that that's impossible. But writing $f'(z) = u(x,y) + i v(x,y)$ for real-valued functions $u,v$ does not seem to help.

So my next idea was to assume that $f(z) = u(x,y)$ for real $z$. But $f'(z) = {d\over dz} f(z)$ and what I want is partial derivatives so that I can show that the derivative does not satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations. So this idea does not work either.

> Please could someone explain to me how to prove this claim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of complex differentiation,
$$
f'(z) := \lim_{h \to 0, h \in \mathbb{C}} \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}
$$
implies *in particular* that if $f'(z)$ exists then it also equals
$$
\lim_{h \to 0, h \in \mathbb{R}}\frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}.
$$
Now if $z$ is a real number, this is just the formula for a derivative in the real numbers. Which is certainly a real number.